# Without installing FTDI driver, can an application dependent on it be deployed?

Tags: installation, windows-10, ftdi

I am developing a Win10 C# application dependent on a third party library, which enables me to control a USB3 device.
By trial and error, I found that I needed to run FTD3XXDriver_WHQLCertified_v1.3.0.4_Installer.exe, which in the end populated the SysWOW64 with FTD3XX.dll and System32\Drivers with FTDIBUS3.sys and the ancillary files and folder.

I would like to run my application from a USB thumb drive on different PC's in my organization without installing any of the drivers. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: To the best of my knowledge you cannot address an FTDI device if the driver is not installed.

But windows normally install the driver automatically via the windows updater. At least, this is the case for the USB 2 devices of FTDI i.e. 232 family. I do not have a FT60X here to test if the windows updater has a driver ready for this as well.
If the driver is installed via the updater you have to bundle the FTD3XX.DLL with your application as it is not part of the "windows standard" driver. At least this was the case for the FTD2XX.DLL.

Long story short: connect your device to a computer without preinstalled driver. Check if the driver is installed via the windows updater. If this is the case, you mostlikely just need to bundle the FTD3XX.DLL with you application.